# How to change color of radio button in angular material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm struggling with the next problem. I'm trying to change the color of the angular material 2 [radio button](https://material.angular.io/components/component/radio) on PROPER way, without overriding css. By default, it uses accent color of the material theme, but I want to use the primary.

Other components have color property like [checkbox](https://material.angular.io/components/component/checkbox), [button](https://material.angular.io/components/component/button), etc...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: angular/material2 has not yet added the `color` attribute in the [MdRadioButton](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/radio/radio.ts#L329) class as in the [MdCheckbox](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/checkbox/checkbox.ts#L193).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles across this issue, you can now use the color property on MatRadioButton components. Here is the link to the GitHub issue where I was corrected:

- https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9439

Comment: The color property doesn't work. All you can do is used predefined colours, like the example here: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-ethbcx?file=app/app.component.html
Adding an attribute color="#54b76d" doesn't work. This is not the correct answer by a long shot.

Comment: The original question asked to use the primary color of the template, which is why I gave the answer the way I did. If the OP had asked about how to use a non-template color, then I would've answered a different way.

Answer (score 7):

ng-deep is depricated. Copy this code into your styles.scss file. It will work.

```
.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
opacity: 0 !important; /*click effect color change*/
background-color: #422873 !important;  }

.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle {
background-color: #422873 !important; /*inner circle color change*/  }

.mat-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-outer-circle {
border-color: #422873 !important; /*outer ring color change*/  }
```

Answer (score 5):

To change **color of the mat radio button** paste the following in your module (like app.module.ts)

```
providers: [{
    provide: MAT_RADIO_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
    useValue: { color: 'primary' },
}]
```

Now the color look like this
[image]

Comment: Thank you for that! Just adding that color can get one of the values: 'primary' | 'accent' | 'warn'

Comment: This is the actual solution - you shouldn't need to rely on `ng-deep`, special properties, etc to override this.  Updating the default to be the expected value so you don't inadvertently mess up your styles is the right way to go.

Answer (score 4):

The radio-button component hasn't input for change the color.
You need to add the following lines in your .scss file:

```
/deep/ .mat-radio-outer-circle {
.mat-radio-checked & {
      border-color: #3f51b5;
    }
}

/deep/ .mat-radio-inner-circle {
    background-color: #3f51b5;
}

/deep/ .mat-radio-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
    background-color: rgba(#3f51b5, 0.26);
}
```

Comment: `/deep/` is being deprecated and only works view Emulated view encapsulation.

Comment: you can use ::ng-deep instead of /deep/

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me

```
.mat-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-outer-circle , .mat-radio-outer-circle {
  border-color: blue !important;
}

.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle{
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: angular 7 its `::ng-deep` b4 the selectors, and no need for the `!important`